# Oracle Application Express - APEX Report Region - How to use date range slider for date columns (start date - end date)

Tags: jquery, sql, oracle, date, jquery-ui-slider

I have created a report region with 7 columns including(start date and end date) having calenders. Now i want to implement date range slider removing those calender selection from each row. e.g. http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#quickStart
Also i want to store the start date and end date in an item.
How do i achieve it. Plz suggest

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to create a date range slider for each row of your report. In that case we will have to generate a DIV with a unique ID for each row. If you have an ID in your row as well, we can use this ID as a postfix for the slider DIV ID. Let's assume you right now have the following query behind your report:

```
select event_id
,      event_name
,      start_date
,      end_date
from   events
```

Where you have a calendar widget generated in the dates columns somehow.
Okay, now first start by hiding the start_date and the end_date columns so they are not visible anymore. Later maybe you can remove them.

Then select an extra column which will contain the new slider:

```
select event_id
,      event_name
,      start_date
,      end_date
,      null as slider
from   events
```

Now go to report attributes and edit the slider column. Go to Column Formatting and here we are going to add the HTML expression that's going to be our DIV for the slider. We also add a piece of javascript that will generate the slider for us, and bind the change event. Click the [Insert column value] link to find your ID column. Following my example above it will look something like this:

```
<div id="slider#EVENT_ID#"></div>
<script>
  $("#slider#EVENT_ID#").dateRangeSlider();
  $("#slider").bind("valuesChanging", function(e, data) {
    HandleSliderChange(#EVENT_ID#, data);
  });
</script>
```

Now you will have to define the HandleSliderChange function somewhere so that you can handle the event. It will pass you the ID of the event/row, and the new dates van be found in the data parameter. Use that to set your page items or handle it in whatever way you desire.

Of course there might be some other things you want to do such as setting the initial dates of the slider, but this should give a good impression of a possible path to take.